# Flex: convert VideoPlayer.currentTime to string "00:00:00:000"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datetime, video, format

what about this one:

I want to format the currentTime displayed by a videoPlayer component inside flex, something like : `8230.999 to something like 01:59:59:999 which is "hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds"`

I trie different sets of codes but they can't get it to work because currentTime is nor a correct miliseconds time as it adds a floating 3 digit point to seconds;

so instead of : `2000ms it outputs 2.000`

something people like me just can't understand!

thanx for any help :)

### UPDATE

I still have problem with milliseconds.
here's the current MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function convert_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var val:Number = new Number(inPut.text); //inPut.text = 1000.001

                //val = val * 1000;
                outPut.text = timeFormat(val);
            }
            public static function timeFormat(value:Number):String
            {
                var milliseconds:Number  = value % 1000;
                var seconds:Number  = Math.floor((value/1000) % 60);
                var minutes:Number  = Math.floor((value/60000) % 60);
                var hours:Number  = Math.floor((value/3600000) % 24);

                var s_miliseconds:String     = (milliseconds<10 ? "00" : (milliseconds<100 ? "0" : ""))+ String(milliseconds);
                var s_seconds:String     = seconds < 10 ? "0" + String(seconds) : String(seconds); 
                var s_minutes:String     = minutes < 10 ? "0" + String(minutes) : String(minutes); 
                var s_hours:String     = hours < 10 ? "0" + String(hours) : String(hours);

                return s_hours  + ":" + s_minutes  + ":" + s_seconds + '.'+s_miliseconds;
                // returns 00:00:01.000.0009999999999763531 should return 00:00:01.001
                // I still have problem with milliseconds
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextInput x="240" y="72" id="inPut" text="1000.001"/>
    <s:TextInput x="240" y="140" id="outPut"/>
    <s:Button x="274" y="107" label="convert" id="convert" click="convert_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Since the result from the currentTime property is in seconds, you could use (currentTime % 1) * 1000 to get the correct millisecond count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A correct one:

I made this one. A complete class.

```
package com.strangemother.utils
{
    public class Time extends Object
    {

        public function Time()
        {
        }

        public static function timeFormat(value:int):String
        {
            var seconds:Number  = value % 60;
            var minutes:Number  = Math.floor((value % 3600 ) /60);

            var minuteString:String     = minutes < 10 ? "0" + String(minutes) + ":" : String(minutes) + ":";   
            var secondString:String     = seconds < 10 ? "0" + String(seconds) : String(seconds);
            return minuteString + secondString;
        }


    }
}
```

---

this works - Googled it.

```
var secondsPerMinute = 60;
var minutesPerHour = 60;
function convertSecondsToHHMMSS(intSecondsToConvert) {
var hours = convertHours(intSecondsToConvert);
var minutes = getRemainingMinutes(intSecondsToConvert);
minutes = (minutes == 60) ? "00" : minutes;
var seconds = getRemainingSeconds(intSecondsToConvert);
return hours+" : "+minutes+" : "+seconds;
}
function convertHours(intSeconds) {
var minutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes/minutesPerHour);
return hours;
}
function convertMinutes(intSeconds) {
return Math.floor(intSeconds/secondsPerMinute);
}
function getRemainingSeconds(intTotalSeconds) {
return (intTotalSeconds%secondsPerMinute);
}
function getRemainingMinutes(intSeconds) {
var intTotalMinutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
return (intTotalMinutes%minutesPerHour);
}

trace(convertSecondsToHHMMSS(13345));
```

Comment: Thanx Glycerin, but the code you provided doesn't work:

I hade to declare vars as int (var hours:int) and also the miliseconds format s not what flash video ouputs, as I said above, the miliseconds formt contains a 3 digits after the float, something like:

trace(convertSecondsToHHMMSS(13345.123)); 

but thanx anyway :)

Comment: When I get home tonight I know of another that'll work if you still need the answer... In fact I know where I can get the code. - 15 minutes I'll have it for you dude.

Comment: I'm very sorry - I notice you need hours as well as minutes and seconds. 

I'll recode that class for you tonight if no one else does it.

Comment: thanx again man, unfortuntly this also didn't return the correct format : i used timeFormat(1.500) which is 1 second and a half, instead of returning 00:01 it returned 25:00. the best was to return 00:00:01:500. Thanx again

Comment: No way?! I use this live. I'll check it tonight for you. I'll try and make a working one.

Comment: I updated the post above using the function you sent. the only problem now is with milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Thanx to the help of both [Glycerine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235146/glycerine) and [Zaren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263860/zaren) and by combining their suggestions, I come up with this class:

```
public class Format
    {

        public static function currentTime(value:Number):String //example value in mis: 1000
        {
            value = value * 1000; // convert video currentTime 1.000 to 1000

            var milliseconds:Number  = Math.round(((value/1000) % 1) * 1000);
            var seconds:Number  = Math.floor((value/1000) % 60);
            var minutes:Number  = Math.floor((value/60000) % 60);
            var hours:Number  = Math.floor((value/3600000) % 24);

            var s_miliseconds:String     = (milliseconds<10 ? "00" : (milliseconds<100 ? "0" : ""))+ String(milliseconds);
            var s_seconds:String     = seconds < 10 ? "0" + String(seconds) : String(seconds); 
            var s_minutes:String     = minutes < 10 ? "0" + String(minutes) : String(minutes); 
            var s_hours:String     = hours < 10 ? "0" + String(hours) : String(hours);

            return s_hours  + ":" + s_minutes  + ":" + s_seconds + '.'+s_miliseconds;

        }
    }
```

I use it like this:

```
// caculate playhead time       
var value:Number = new Number(video_player_monitor.currentTime);
imghri_playhead.text = Format.currentTime(value);
```

Hope it helps someone else. Again, Thank you guys for your support ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a Date formatter to generate the proper output...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var seconds:Number = 10000;

        private function formatTime(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var stamp:Date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, seconds, 0)
            txtTime.text = fmtTime.format(stamp); 
        }
     ]]>
     </mx:Script>
     <mx:DateFormatter id="fmtTime" formatString="JJ:NN:SS"/>
     <mx:Text id="txtTime" text=""/>
     <mx:Button click="formatTime(event)"/>
</mx:Application>
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanx Zaren but this doesn't solve my problem. i'm working with a special time format which is the length of the video, it's not a date format because the video time can be 30:00:00:000 (hh:mm:ss:mis) so date formatter is not working. flash video returns miliseconds in a special format, so instead of 10000 (10 seconds) it returns 10000.000 (notice the 3 floating digits).
thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert a string like "00:02:31:76" to a number of seconds.  If anyone is interested, here's the class for that:

---

package  {

```
public class ConvertStringToTime {

    public static function processTimeString(timeString:String):Number {

        var timePieceArray:Array = timeString.split(":");

        var milliseconds:Number = Number(timePieceArray[3])/100;
        var seconds:Number = Number(timePieceArray[2]);
        var minutesInSeconds:Number = Number(timePieceArray[1])*60;
        var hoursInSeconds:Number = Number(timePieceArray[0])*60*60;

        var timeInSeconds:Number = hoursInSeconds + minutesInSeconds + seconds + milliseconds

        return timeInSeconds;
    }

}
```

}

Then, if I want to use it, I can call, for example: 
trace(ConvertStringToTime.processTimeString("00:02:03:25"));

Answer (score 0):

Why not this here:

```
var time:String = getTimeString(4200000);trace( time );
function getTimeString($milliSeconds:int) : String
{
    var seconds:int = ($milliSeconds /1000)%60;
    var minutes:int = (($milliSeconds /1000)/60)%60;
    var hours:int = $milliSeconds /1000/60/60;

    var h:String = hours<10 ? '0' + hours : ''+hours;
    var m:String = minutes<10 ? '0' + minutes : ''+minutes;
    var s:String = seconds<10 ? '0' + seconds : ''+seconds;

    return h+':'+m+':'+s;
}
```